# How do I create a function that creates a color square like in the picture below?

Tags: excel, vba, color-codes

How do I create a function that creates a color square like in the picture below?

So, I need to create a function that generates a color square as below:

[image]

I tried to do that...

```
Sub GenererCarreCouleur()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Changez le numéro de feuille si nécessaire
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:G8")
    
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, count As Integer
    count = 1
    
    For i = 1 To 8
        For j = 1 To 7
            rng.Cells(i, j).Value = count
            rng.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = GetCouleur(count)
            count = count + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetCouleur(ByVal valeur As Integer) As Long
    ' Ajoutez autant de cas que nécessaire pour couvrir toutes les valeurs jusqu'à 56
    Select Case valeur
        Case 1 To 7
            GetCouleur = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Noir
        Case 8 To 14
            GetCouleur = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' Blanc
        Case 15 To 21
            GetCouleur = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Rouge
        ' Ajoutez d'autres cas ici en fonction de vos besoins
        Case Else
            GetCouleur = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' Noir par défaut
    End Select
End Function
```

But it's wrong

Comment: *But it's wrong* is not a meaningful problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Create it with `ColorIndex`

```vb
Sub ColorSqu()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Cells.RowHeight = 25.8
    Cells.ColumnWidth = 4.4
    Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    For r = 1 To 8
        For c = 1 To 7
            With Cells(r, c)
                .Value = 7 * (r - 1) + c
                .Interior.ColorIndex = .Value
                If r + c = 2 Then .Font.Color = vbWhite
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Small hint: Make it a habit to use `Long` instead of `Integer` in VBA, especially when it comes to row or column numbers. Why? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/7599798

Comment: This code generates square cells. `Cells.Select : Selection.ColumnWidth = 5.29 :  Selection.RowHeight = 30`

Comment: @FunThomas In general it is right. But it is overkilled for this case.

Comment: @taller: No, it's not overkill. Integer take the same amount of memory but come with the price tag that the runtime needs to ensure that an overflow happens when you use more than the 16bit. So it has only disadvantages and no advantage. Basically, the data type `Integer` is only needed in extremely rare cases where you call an interface (eg an old API routine) that expects 16bit. Therefore my advice to not use it at all.